# how to get windows command line string?

Tags: string, perl, cmd, carriage-return

I made a simple executable (`string.exe`) from the following code. You can not change this file.

```
$| = 1;
foreach my $i (1..10) {
    print "test : $i\r";
    sleep 2;
}
```

I want grab the output from that program in real-time. I attempted to do so with the following code:

```
open(my $fh, '-|', 'string.exe') or die $!;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    print $line;
}
```

But I can not get the output in real-time. In my opinion, this is due to the use of carriage return (`\r`).

Comment: I`m test something...

Answer (score 3):

`readline` (`<>`) reads until a line feed is encountered, but you send carriage returns instead. `readline` is somewhat configurable (via `$/`), but not to the point where you can instruct it to read until a CR or LF is returned.

`sysread`, otoh, returns as soon as data is available. This is exactly what you want.

```
$| = 1;
while (sysread($fh, my $buf, 64*1024)) {
    print $buf;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set your [`$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) to `\r`:

```
local $/ = "\r";
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Don't forget to flush your output in that program too.

Answer (score 0):

> how to get windows command line string?

If I understand your question, you could use something like

```
local $cmd = join " ", $0, @ARGV;
print $cmd;
```

Answer (score 0):

Testing [choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030675/choroba)'s answer about the [`$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# As described in http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Safe-Pipe-Opens
my $pid = open(KID_TO_READ, "-|") // die "can't fork: $!";

# Parent
if ($pid) {
    local $/ = "\r";
    while (<KID_TO_READ>) {
        use Data::Dump;
        dd $_;
    }
    close(KID_TO_READ) or warn "kid exited $?";

# Child
} else {
    local $| = 1;
    foreach my $i (1..10) {
        print "test : $i\r";
        sleep 2;
    }
    exit;
}
```

Outputs:

```
"test : 1\r"
"test : 2\r"
"test : 3\r"
"test : 4\r"
"test : 5\r"
"test : 6\r"
"test : 7\r"
"test : 8\r"
"test : 9\r"
"test : 10\r"
```

Ironically, this test won't work on Windows:

```
'-' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
kid exited 256 at test_RS.pl line 14.
```

However, this still confirms that the `$RS` will work as documented.